# How can I send a parameter to partial view without the need of a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view in my MVC app which I load into a container dom element. I do this by first calling the controller, like so:

```
$(container).load('/xxx/GetPartialView');
```

In the controller I return the partial view:

```
public PartialViewResult GetPartialView()
{
   return PartialView("SomePartial", null);
}
```

This works just fine. However, I would like to send a parameter (just a simple string value) along from the controller to the partial view I'm creating. This I understand, can be done by the use of a model, like for example:

```
public PartialViewResult GetPartialView(string someValue)
{
   return PartialView("SomePartial", new SomeDummyModel(someValue));
}
```

But I would like to avoid the model instance if possible, as it seems like a lot of overhead. I want to just send the string value as a parameter. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of passing a custom class such as `SomeDummyModel` you can simply pass `someValue`. Assuming that `someValue` is `string` from your explanation, that would mean you would accept `string` in the `@model` of your partialView.

controller

```
public PartialViewResult GetPartialView(string someValue)
{
 return PartialView("SomePartial", someValue);
}
```

partial

```
@model string
<div>Hello, @Model :)</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ViewData object to pass simple items like that.

```
    public PartialViewResult GetPartialView()
    {
          ViewData["someValue"] = "hello";
          return PartialView("SomePartial", null);
    }
```

And then in the view access it:

```
<div>@ViewData["someValue"].ToString() :)</div>
```

This works without a model.
You can put pretty much anything into the ViewData object, you just need to cast it out